# Cannot get a web page in python anywhere (the hosting site)

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am trying to get a basic web page in Python Anywhere. I cannot view a "home" page.

I configured the `WSGI` file as per the instructions and have the site working on my Linux box fine.

Please help!

Here is my `wsgi.py` file:

```
 # +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
 import os
 import sys

## assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/my_username/projects/my_project         /settings.py'
path = '/home/mickpc/solar_update'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is the start of the error code:

```
2014-12-10 03:29:04,746 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-12-10 03:29:04,746 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI     application")
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in     exception
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in     error
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in     _log
2014-12-10 03:29:04,747 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg,     args, exc_info, func, extra)
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in     makeRecord
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info,     func)
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in     __init__
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in      currentThread
2014-12-10 03:29:04,748 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django     /core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :    self.load_middleware()
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
2014-12-10 03:29:04,749 :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.clickjacking: "No module named clickjacking"
```

The tree of my site:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── myfig.png
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py~
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── index.html~
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.py~
│   ├── urls.pyc 
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── newapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── foo.png
│   ├── graph.py
│   ├── graph.py~
│   ├── graph.pyc
│   ├── Images
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── myfig.png
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── green-business-graph.jpg
│   │   ├── HourlyProfileGraph.gif
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── index.html~
│   │   ├── pic_mountain.jpg
│   │   └── url
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.py~ 
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.py~
│   └── views.pyc
└── README.md
```

views.py (newapp)

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

import graph

def index(request):

    graph.generate()
```

urls.py (solar_update)

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', include('newapp.urls')),
)
```

here is the suggested wsgi.py:

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
import os
import sys

## assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/my_username/projects/my_project/settings.py'
path = '/home/my_username/projects'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: You should be a bit more descriptive in how your stack is setup: What is the full stack trace of the error? How does your `WSGI` file look, which extra libraries/frameworks are you using to build your site, what does your actual code look like?

Comment: Thanks for adding the `WSGI` file, but at a minimum a full stack trace is required to see the full extend of the error. A few things I notice about your `WSGI` file: Strange (illegal) indentation for the `import` statements and an absolute reference to your homedir.

Comment: There: with a full error stack trace, it is now showing your why it is not bootstrapping: `No module named clickjacking`. It looks like you are wrapping a non existing module named [`clickjacking`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/) as middleware, which, of course, fails. Did you install it remotely?

Comment: should the wsgi path look like home/mickpc/solar_update ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, no, just matplotlib and numpy.

Comment: @Micheal: I highly doubt that this path is correct, since it points to a location on your local development machine. Yet, it is not the error. It complains about a missing dependency, the `clickjacking` module. This could, of course, be connected to a faulty path for it might try and search in the wrong location. So my suggestion is your first fix the path to point to a correct location on your Python Anywhere environment. Then make sure the mentioned Django middleware module is installed.

Comment: I am new to django, could you please give me the exact path?
is it home/mickpc/solar_update?

Comment: As much as I like to, I cannot. I am not familiar with the Python Anywhere environment. The path setting is very specific to your use case, your environment and your setup. It also has nothing to do with Django directly. I suggest your consult the documentation over at Python Anywhere to see what they allow/suggest this path to be.

Comment: I did use the suggested method, see the addition of the wsgi.py, thank you Timuasn.

Comment: @Micheal: Okay, then we must assume the path is correct, the only thing remaining then is the missing Django Clickjacking module. Again, I'm not knowledgeable about Python Anywhere, but you should install this module there in order for your application to boot, or remove its dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The layout of your project suggests you're using a version of Django that is newer than the one that PythonAnywhere has installed. I'm guessing (from the presence of a migrations folder) that you're using 1.7. If you want to use Django 1.7 on PythonAnywhere, you'll have to use a virtualenv. There are instructions in the PythonAnywhere help pages.